# replace text with sed in linux

Tags: linux, sed

I have the below text in a file

```
path_tryuio=$path_opt/GMT/$CARGMT_VERSION
```

I want to replace the above text with the below text using `sed`

```
$path_track/GMT/cayu/station/GMT/$CARGMT_VERSION
```

Where version is a variable.

How can we do this?

Comment: are `$path_opt` and `$path_track` also variable that should be expanded?

Comment: yes, they are defined in the file

Comment: Try `sed -i 's/path_tryuio=$path_opt//GMT//$CARGMT_VERSION/path_tryuio=$path_track//GMT//cayu//station//GMT//$CARGMT_VERSION/g' *`

Comment: can we put the strings in a variable and then use it in sed?

Answer (score 0):

Since the path contains slashes, you probably don't want to use the common `/` character as the delimiter for sed.  Here, instead of using `/` I use `^`:

```
$ echo $path_tryuio
/this/is/some_path
$ echo $path_tryuio | sed -e "s^/is^^"
/this/some_path
```

Also note the use of double quotes instead of single quotes – the shell does not expand variables within single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you wanted the following modifed

```
        path_tryuio=$path_opt/GMT/$CARGMT_VERSION
```

and not what's on the right of `=` as is normally to be expected, you can achieve this using `sed` as:

```
sed -e 's|path_tryuio=$path_opt/\(GMT/$CARGMT_VERSION\)|$path_track/GMT/cayu/station/\1|'
```

Note that in the above sed command what we have are single quotes, so the `$` variables will not interpolated, rather as literal strings.

The `$` in `$path_opt` won't be treated as end of pattern space, since there is text after it.